# Marking an Excel Spreadsheet with a value range

Tags: excel

I teach a budgeting course for my professional association.  As part of that course, students are required to submit a draft budget as part of their marks.  The budget template that I have to use is kindof set in stone.  The association offers it's courses at various college locations and I can't just arbitrarily change it's contents.

That being said, marking this assignment is a pain in the neck!  I'm looking for an easy way to be able to compare the values in a cell, and then mark it correct or incorrect, if it is within an expected range..

For example, students are required to estimate the expenses for the current year.  If their estimate is within $200 +/- of what the answer key states, then I would mark their answer correct.

I am not a coder by trade, but rather an armchair coder who will search out and self teach what I need to solve my problem, so I'm not afraid of a bit of homework myself.  I have not been able to find any solution so far.  Right now, my students submit their assignment hardcopy, and I manually mark their spreadsheets.  Tedious to say the least.  Any searches I try to perform for academic marking of an Excel spreadsheet only return solutions to use Excel as a tracking tool for student marks, which is not what I'm looking for.

My college uses Desire2Learn as their online platform for content delivery, and students can submit their material electronically, I want an easy way to determine if they have completed the spreadsheet correctly.

Any help, or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to tackle this problem but this might be something simple if the layout of the sheets doesn't change. You could create a worksheet with 3 sheets. 
1. a sheet to copy their work into
2. "Master" sheet with the correct answers
3. "Grading" sheet that has formulas that calculate the difference (possibly within a range). For example IF(ABS(Sheet 1!B20 - Sheet 2!B20)>200,"Correct","Incorrect"). Calculates the absolute value of the difference between the same cell address on 2 different sheets then compares to the expected answer and returns Correct or Incorrect.

You would still have to copy their work into your master worksheet one at a time. Remember this only works if their worksheet layout doesn't change.

Post a rely along with a sample of the data if you need something more flexible.

Comment: Thank you so much, this might work.  Knowing which formula to work is where I was getting stumped.  I'm new to StackOverflow and haven't figured out how to attach a file to my posts...  Perhaps you could provide me with some guidance and I can attach the exact spreadsheet.  The layout of the template won't change, I do have the ability to force them to use a template without changing it.

Comment: I'm actually new to stackoverflow providing answers. I don't think you can attach file to a post. You can post an image though so if you want to do a screen shot with a part of the data that will help. We would probably need to email in order to exchange a worksheet.